# Windows 7 Backup Image - Mount to Virtual PC?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, vhd

I took a backup of my PC a while ago, and forgot what was on the backup.  I noticed it created a VHD file, but I was wondering if that was safe to run in Virtual PC without corrupting the image to restore to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see what's in the VHD and maybe pull back a few files, you can mount the VHD as another volume under your existing copy of Windows 7. Get to the **Disk Management** console (it's under **Computer Management**), and then select `Action` / `Attach VHD`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about corrupting it... make a backup of your backup :)

It probably won't work in Virtual PC because the DRM in Windows (Product Activation) will think you've moved it to new hardware.

If you just want to browse the files in the image, [mount it](http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2009/01/15/mount-a-vhd-within-windows-7-server-2008-r2.aspx) and use Explorer.